# Is getting objects from aws s3 bucket slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am using S3Objects.withPrefix() to get 100k objects from an s3 bucket located in east region. It took more than 10 seconds to return all objects. That was kind of slow. Does anyone have similar experience? I thought getting objects from s3 buckets should be much faster? Or I was using the wrong API? Right now, these 100k objects are located under the 10 sub directories, such as /North/Maine/Town1/,  /North/Maine/Town2, .../North/Maine/Town10. Will it be faster if i put them under the same sub directory, such as: /North/Maine/Towns/ ? thanks

Comment: Are you doing any concurrency/multi threading?  Maybe try a few process/thread filter on each town.

Comment: Guessing this is a Java SDK question. Please apply an explicit tag to your questions to help us. And when you say 'get', do you actually mean get (as in 'download from S3') or do you mean list (as in 'give me a list of objects with the given prefix')? I presume the latter. Please clarify.

Comment: yes, i need download the objects from s3

Comment: Downloading 100k objects in 10 seconds doesn't seem particularly slow to me. What kind of performance are you looking for?

Comment: I have a client which calls our service every 3 seconds and we need process these 100k objects and return results to the client.

Comment: Are you wanting to _list_ the objects, or _download_ the objects? If downloading, then what are you doing with the files once they are downloaded?

Comment: Does the list of files depend on the request the client makes, or can you cache the downloads in advance on local disk (assuming you're not running in Lambda)? Make sure EC2 is in the same region as the S3 bucket. Also, read up on TransferManager to parallelize options (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-downloads-for-optimal-speed/) And read this guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html)